# Internal server error when opening my inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox

When I try to open [my inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_=1524645677508), the page takes a long time to load, and gives a 500 internal server error, it works fine on other sites (including SO Meta), but fails at Stack Overflow.

This is the error I'm getting inside my console:

> ```
> inbox:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
> ```

and when I manually go to the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_=1524645677508) that failed to load, it also gives me the 500 internal server error robot.

Comment: Hmm, that works for me. I'm on Chrome, in case it matters

Comment: Somebody probably has to repair the dbase for your user account.   It is never very obvious whether SO employees still visit meta, if nobody responds then use https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f

Comment: I'm getting the exact same thing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309412/152515